# not able to run java program in eclipse using jdk 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to run very simple application  in eclipse :

```
package hello;

 public class RunMain {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("hello neha!!");

    }
    }
```

it shows an error in console: 
Could not find or load main class hello.RunMain
It uses jdk 1.7What could be the possible reason

Comment: Did you save this file in Eclipse inside the package hello?

Comment: I have specified the error above

Comment: No one who fails to understand CLASSPATH should use Eclipse until they do.

Comment: yes.. i saved this file in hello package only

Comment: Do you see a RunMain.class file anywhere in the project directory structure?

Comment: is this part of an imported project?

Comment: @ALBI, could you show us a screen capture of your project structure? Something similar to http://cmenness.dyndns.org/webdoc/gwt-docs-20081026/image/StockWatcherEclipseProject.png

Comment: @ALBI did you find what was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Right Click Run As -> RunConfiguration

In Main tab:
Main Class: hello.RunMain

In ClassPath tab:
under user entries add the project(from add projects)

Click on Run.